# Return type is non-null and based on input type

Tags: typescript

I am curious if it is possible to have one `getOrFail` function that does what I have below. As you can see the contents of both functions are the same, but the argument types are different.

```
export const getStringOrFail = (value: string | null, message: string = 'getStringOrFail error'): string => {
  if (value !== null) return value
  throw new Error(message);
}

export const getNumberOrFail = (value: number | null, message: string = 'getNumberOrFail error'): number => {
  if (value !== null) return value
  throw new Error(message);
}
```

I tried using a generic  and returning that but then it's possible to return `null`.

How can I define one function that does what I have above?

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is define a generic parameter, which doesn't include `null`:

```js
export const getOrFail = <T extends string | number>(value: T | null, message: string = 'getOrFail error'): T => {
  if (value !== null) return value
  throw new Error(message);
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wObBgeSgMQEMBLAGzgF44AeAFTlBmGQBNU50pjkM4AfOMgCuAWwBGwKAD4AFADdCpIcABccegOGlSAGjgjgqVISxrO3XlQDkWXARLlJUaFYCUa+hSlwA3gCg4OGIAMzh5RWU4AEIKKi1SVzgobCEoZDgFJWAAuBgAC2cAd0FgYoBRKGcoGQMjE2BXAG4-AF8gA)

As @jcalz suggested, if you want to go more generic and allow everything except `null`. You can use `{} | undefined | void` instead of `string | number`:

```js
export const getOrFail = <T extends {} | undefined | void>(value: T | null, message: string = 'getOrFail error'): T => {
  if (value !== null) return value
  throw new Error(message);
}
```

Comment: Only allows string or number :)

Comment: You could make the generic constraint something like `T extends {} | undefined | void` which allows just about anything except `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Try generic, but `T` should extend `{}`.

```
export function getOrFail<T extends {}>(value: T | null | undefined, message: string = "getNumberOrFail error"): T {
  if (value != null) return value;
  throw new Error(message);
}
```

`{}` allows everything except null or undefined.

More info [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7648#issuecomment-200144219).

Comment: Good thinking with `{}`. Just note that the implementation checks only for `null` not `undefined`. So either `undefined` should be included in `T` or the implementation needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note another approach for completeness (it's not necessarily better than any of the others), using a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) return type that [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu)s `null`:

```
export const getOrFail = <T>(
  value: T | null,
  message: string = "getOrFail error"
) => {
  if (value !== null) return value as Exclude<T, null>;
  throw new Error(message);
};
```

And check how it behaves:

```
const bool = getOrFail(true); // boolean
const nevr = getOrFail(null); // never
const undef = getOrFail(undefined); // undefined
const strng = getOrFail(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "hello" : null); // string
```

That last one has a parameter of type `string | null` and the return type is `Exclude<string | null, null>`, or just `string`.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wObBgeSgMQEMBLAGzgF44AeAFQD4AKAWACg44A3Q0gV2ABccWnAA+cZL1KkANGw4BbYKlSEsQ9FGLIMlOACIsuAiXLAoUaPrYBKSvTgBveXGIAzOI259gcAIQUVJLSdlDYvFDIXDz8cISocACiIAh8ACbAdDISUqT0ANwuMAAWlgDuEsAViRbQjEoqasA2hawAvq1sSGjwAEYQEORURnhEZIwwUPwtcAD0s3D9g8CEyF0o6JWcUHojJuPBpDPzW+brPXC8yBkew9ijpoxXN9rAaccLz8Bur2nnm5odLt7vtSIwALKEEoAOigqzSEAUjDs1DgAAZoQBWOAAfgMxWA0gg+jgQkOHzgmm0GDYQA)